# How to print the results in tab separted using linux commands?

Tags: linux, shell, echo

```sh
for i in `cat /home/htvam/muthu/mbovis/uk_fastq/trim_files/sub_list.txt`
do

   for j in `cat /home/htvam/muthu/mbovis/uk_fastq/trim_files/fn_pos.txt`
   do

        echo "$i\t\c"
        echo "$j\t\c"   
        echo "$(samtools view "$i"_dup_mapped_sorted.bam  NC_000962.3:$j-$j | awk '{if($2<1023) print}' | wc -l)\t\c"
        echo "$(samtools view "$i"_dup_mapped_sorted.bam  NC_000962.3:$j-$j | awk '{if($2>1023) print}' | wc -l)"

done
done
```

**sub_list.txt contains**

- ERR125598
- ERR125599

**fn_pos.txt contains**

- 14401
- 62049
- 71336
- 4386228
- 4394265
- 4395387
- 4395804

It output results like:

[image: result of the code]

But I need the next sample "i" in a list should print the tab instead of newline like

[image: expected outout]

Comment: If I get it right `sub_list.txt` should be in inner loop not outer. All your `echo` should ends with `\t\c` And for a new line just add empty `echo` between two `done`. Please add output as peace of code instead of picture and take reproduceable example next time.

Comment: Note that `echo \t` is not guaranteed to print a tab at all. If you want _reliable_ behavior with backslash-escape sequences, you should be using `printf` instead of `echo`; the [unix.se] question [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) has an excellent answer that goes into more details.

Comment: Also, [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). The right way to iterate over input from a file is covered in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).